# Почему скрипт не работает на айфоне в сафари?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, safari

Почему код не работает на айфоне в сафари?

```
$('.ortop-input input').on('click', function () {
    var sizedata = $('.option-size .options-list input:checked').attr('data-size');
    $(this).parent().next().find("label:contains(" + "'" + " " + sizedata + "'" + ")").trigger('click');
    if ($('#yashiki-kolesa-input, #yashiki-napravl-input').is(':disabled')) {
        $('.yashiki-kolesa-value input').attr('disabled', false);
        $('.yashiki-napravl-value input').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#yashiki-kolesa-input').attr('disabled', false);
        $('#yashiki-napravl-input').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
    }
});
```

Comment: Консоль ничего не говорит?

Comment: Как её открыть на айфоне в сафари? На десктопе всё ок.

Comment: Если нет Мака, то можете использовать https://github.com/liriliri/eruda

Answer (score 0):

Атрибут `disabled` не принимает значение `true/false`.

Вместо этого попробуйте `false` использовать метод `prop`

`$('.target').prop('disabled', false);`

или удалять атрибут с помощью метода `removeAttr`

`$('.target').removeAttr('disabled');`